# Problema com Primary Key ambiente_id em vez de id no TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

estou tentando criar uma tabela no banco MySQL, com TypeORM aonde o id é `ambiente_id` (`nome da tabela` + `_` + `id`).

Erro:

> ER_WRONG_AUTO_KEY: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
> code: 'ER_WRONG_AUTO_KEY',
> errno: 1075,
> sqlMessage: 'Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key',
> sqlState: '42000',
> index: 0,
> sql: 'ALTER TABLE `ambiente` ADD `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT'

Minha entidade:

```
@Entity()
export class Ambiente {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({name: 'ambiente_id'})
   ambiente_id: number;
```

Minha database config esta com o `synchronize: true`.

Comment: o erro na verdade era que estava buildando em cima da pasta /dist, não removia e rebuildava, apenas rebuildava em cima da pasta ja criada ai dava erro.